# piping in shell via Python subprocess module

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, pipe

So I'm trying to query for the top 3 CPU "intensive" processes on a given machine, and I found this shell command to do it: `ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -3`

I want to use this data inside a Python script, so I need to be able to capture the output of the above command via the `subprocess` module. The following works, but just returns a huge string since I'm not restricting it to the top 3:

`psResult = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-eo', 'pcpu,user,args'])`

I'm not quite sure how this `subprocess.check_output` works.. in a meager attempt I tried:

`subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-eo', 'pcpu,user,args', '|', 'sort', '-k', '1', '-r', '|', 'head', '-3'])`

Which gives me an error: `ps: illegal argument: |`

How do I use the pipe `|` symbol inside Python, or use some other way to do the sorting without having to do incredible amounts of parsing on the huge string returned by `psResult = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-eo', 'pcpu,user,args'])`?

Thanks!
Regards,
-kstruct

Comment: You could write a shell script containing your code with pipes, then call that from the subprocess module

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass the `shell=True` argument to execute the plain shell command:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -3',
                        shell=True)
```

Alternatively, use the sorting options of ps and Python's built-in string functions like this:

```
raw = subprocess.check_output('ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args --sort -pcpu')
first_three_lines = list(raw.split('\n'))[:3]
```

Answer (score 11):

Some others have suggested using `shell=True`, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10405562/577088) is fine if you are passing trusted input to the shell. However, `shell=True` introduces some insecurities. For security, the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) recommend the following:

```
output=`dmesg | grep hda`
# becomes
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

it should work if you use:

```
subprocess.check_output("ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -3", shell=True)
```

then the command is run exactly like this using `/bin/sh`, so the pipes will work.

Answer (score 1):

Why use external commands at all? Use [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation):

```
import psutil
def cpu_percentage(proc):
    try:
        return proc.get_cpu_percent()
    except psutil.AccessDenied:
        return float('-inf')

top3 = sorted(psutil.process_iter(), key=cpu_percentage, reverse=True)[:3]
for proc in top3:
    # do whatever
```